# Focus on MatInput on page load giving error

Tags: angular8, mat-input

On page load input should be focused

```
<mat-form-field>
          <input matInput #element placeholder="username" >
                 
    <button type="button" (click)="focus()" class="btn btnStyles" >HighLight</button>
```

```
@ViewChild('element') ref:ElementRef;


focus(){
this.ref.nativeElement.focus(); 

}
```

On click of HighLight button its focusing the text box but when i call this method on ngOnInit its giving error Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

```
ngOnInit() {
this.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) interface and to focus on your input inside `ngAfterViewInit()` method (ngOnInit sometimes executes when the view has not been fully initialized, I guess):

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild('element') ref:ElementRef;

   focus(){
      this.ref.nativeElement.focus(); 
   }
  
   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but giving same error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined